# Python setuptools import error (Using NetBeans)

Tags: python, netbeans, setuptools, importerror

I tried to find a question that would answer to this question but wasn't succesful, so I made a new question.

I'm trying to compile my old Python Tic Tac Toe game in NetBeans, but I get the error message

```
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

In my actual code I haven't imported a module named setuptools. As much as I understand the compiler generates a setup.py file and tries to use that setuptools module in there. How can I fix that problem?

I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't in the code as that same code worked perfectly the time when I actually made it and I haven't changed it after that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to install either [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) or [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) in your Python instance.  Follow the directions at either web page.

Comment: Thanks. Installing the setuptools fixed the problem. I tried to find that setuptools before asking, but couldn't find it that time (probably misspelled it).

Comment: note that "Distribute is intended to replace Setuptools as the standard method for working with Python module distributions." You should use this for python 3.

Comment: Yes, since there have been no `setuptools` releases for a number of years and it has not been updated for Python 3, `Distribute` is now the generally recommended choice for providing `easy_install` and the `setuptools` API.

Answer (score 5):

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
tar zxvf setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
cd setuptools-0.6c11
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Satya, but easier to copy&paste:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
tar zxvf setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
cd setuptools-0.6c11
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as above, but since I dont have comment rights here is the working version which ignores the certificate mismatch for ssl auto-redirect :

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
tar zxvf setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
cd setuptools-0.6c11
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```